# Add map as drilldown for pie chart

Tags: highcharts

I have a pie chart and I want to add map drilldown series. How?

http://jsfiddle.net/u03oddrg/1/

```
$('#things-in-brazil').highcharts({
    chart: { type: 'pie'},
    series: [{
        name: 'Things in Brazil',
        data: [
            { name: 'Thing 1', y: 1500 },
            { name: 'Thing 2', y: 2600 }
        ]
    }]
});

var data_for_thing1 = [
    { "hc-key": "br-pa", value: 110 },
    { "hc-key": "br-sc", value: 210 },
    { "hc-key": "br-ap", value: 340 },
    { "hc-key": "br-ba", value: 480 },
    { "hc-key": "br-mt", value: 90 }
];
$('#thing1-by-state').highcharts('Map', {
    mapNavigation: { enabled: false },
    series : [{
        data : data_for_thing1,
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/br/br-all'],
        joinBy: 'hc-key',
        name: 'Thing 1',
        states: { hover: { color: '#BADA55' } },
        dataLabels: { enabled: true, format: '{point.name}' }
    }]
});
```

Comment: Both of charts should be displayed on the same chart, or afer click on the pie char slice, then map should display?

Comment: The second one. I actually did this by adding a drilldown series with "type: 'map'", but the result was a distorted map over a grid and a pie chart with map navigation buttons lol

Comment: You need to catch click event on the slice and then destroy chart and create new one (map);