# drilldown from pie to columns with separate mysql data

Tags: highcharts, drilldown

I am new to highcharts. I am unable to get pie to column chart with separate mysql data.
Suppose I have a data like

```
Publisher  Sections  Counts
 A         Business   2
 B         Sports     7
 C         LifeStyle  8
 A         Sports     0
 A         LifeStyle  4
 C         Business   10
```

In my first level 0, I want to show pie chart based on the field "Sections" and on drilldown, in the next level 1, I want to show column chart displaying all the publishers information for individual sections.(eg:- A & C publishers in Business with counts [2,10],A & B publishers in Sports with counts [7,0] and A & C publishers in Lifestyle with counts [8,4],).

Comment: Have you any parser i.e php which connect with mysql and return data?

Comment: Yes,I have "section.php" & "secpubs.php" which connects with mysql and returns data.

Comment: I don't think you can drilldown from pie chart to column chart. But the pie-pie drilldown would be something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-drilldown/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27727671/add-map-as-drilldown-for-pie-chart

Comment: Thanks, Raeen Hashemi!! Look into this jsfiddle pie to column chart link: jsfiddle.net/nagoba/V4q69/1/. Here the data is static, but I want data dynamic.

Comment: If it works with static data, you need to get your data and prepare any parser which transform this to correct form.

Comment: Thanks, Sebastian!! It is working fine now.